# Stop IIS SMTP Server from sending "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)"

Tags: iis, smtp

I have set the BadMail directory and the 'Send copy of Non-Delivery Report to' fiels is empty but, somehow I am still receiving the failure messages. Is the a way to stop the failure messages?. I am using the default Windows 2008, IIS SMTP Server.

[image: Settings in IIS6]